# Keeping track of Python Class variables that increase when instantiated.

Tags: python

So I have a Python class that is roughly:

```
class Aircraft():
    number_of_airbus = 0
    number_of_boeing = 0
    ...
```

The general idea is that when a class is instantiated either number of airbus or number of Boeing should increase so the next time the class is instantiated the new updated number is provided.

Is this possible or should I be storing total numbers in DB?

Comment: You will get two different results: when you use a class variable you will get the number of objects created ( != existing) in this run of the program, when using a DB it will be permanent count over all runs of the program.

Comment: If you want to refer to variables in the class itself, rather than in an instance of the class, you can refer to `Aircraft.number_of_airbus` for instance.  You can increment them in `init` if you want to keep count that way.  Whether this is the right thing for you to do is another matter.

Comment: @TomKarzes I wouldn't be able to do the increment in the __init__ would it be possible to increment in another method?

Comment: Yes, you can access them from anywhere, as long as the class is defined.

Answer (score 0):

> All variables defined on the class level in Python are considered
>   static (shared among instances)

so when you increase `number_of_airbus` or `number_of_boeing` it should be reflected in all instances of this specific class.

access of variables should be through class name:

```
>>> class Aircraft:
...     n = 1
... 
>>> Aircraft.n
1
>>> air = Aircraft()
>>> air.n
1
>>> Aircraft.n += 1
>>> Aircraft.n
2
>>> air.n
2
```

Hope this is useful